# Organizing layouts with edit text at bottom?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I wanted to make a layout with 3 `LinearLayouts`. In the 2nd `LinearLayout` I would have a `ListView` and the 3rd `LinearLayout` I would have an `EditText` and `Button` at the bottom. This was my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_post"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_status"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_comments"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_comments"
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the design looks great but when I load the app on my phone, I have 2 problems:

1. I don't want to hardcode the LinearLayout heights. I have looked into `layout_weight` but I can't seem to have these `layout_weights` work without running into the 2nd problem below:
2. When I click the `EditText`, the `EditText` is hidden even though I have declared `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` in my activity and I'm not sure why that's happening. Also, the `EditText` and `Button` are not directly at the bottom of the screen which is what I would want. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to add listview as child of linear layout. and avoid fill_parent & use match_parent. if first linear layout is only for textview then don't use it inside of linearlayout. or only use wrap_content instead of a specific layout_height

Here i made some changes hope it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#222dc9">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"
    android:layout_below="@id/view_post"
   ></ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/send_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="send"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and use in Manifest with activity name is

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/material_grey_300"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_comments"
    android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_200"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/send_message"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="send" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use relative layout everywhere? Can you explain why this might be better to do than to using Linear Layouts?